# Need to catch event of the pressing ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF program I have a `ListBox` component and some `ListBoxItems` in it.
When I press on the list's elements, I need to catch the event, but my code doesn't work:

```
    private void mailsListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("-------------"); // even this doesn't work
        switch (mailsListBox.SelectedIndex)
        {
            // this doesn't work too...
            case 0: MessageBox.Show("00"); break;
            case 1: MessageBox.Show("11"); break;
            case 2: MessageBox.Show("22"); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
```

Should I catch event `MouseLeftButtonDown`?

```
       <TabItem Header="Mail" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" IsSelected="True">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <ListBox x:Name="mailsListBox" MouseLeftButtonDown="mailsListBox_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Margin="0,0,0,1"/>
                    <ListBoxItem Content="..." Margin="0,0,0,1" />
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

Comment: Can't you use [`ListBox.SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better if you handle **SelectionChanged** event instead.

Answer (score 1):

As tagaPdyk said you should actually catch the **SelectionChanged** OR the **SelectedIndexChanged** event event like such:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        //maybe check if there actually is a selection
        if(listBox1.SelectedItems[0] != null)
        {
                var item = listBox1.SelectedItems[0];
                //do something with your item
        }
}
```

You can actually get ALL selected items in a listbox(returns an `array`), or just get the 1st item by using `listBox1.SelectedItems[0]`. In your control's `properties` you can define if you want multiselect or not.